# Abstract class constructor Error

Tags: c#

net  abstract class SoapHeader declares constructor  and is implemented like below: I tried to do the same in Visual studio but I get error: constructor must contain body because it is not abstrcat

```
public abstract class SoapHeader
{
    protected SoapHeader();
}

[Serlializable]
public class AuthenticationSoapHeader: SoapHeader,ISerializable
{
    public AthenticationHeader();
    public AthenticationHeader(param1, param2)
}
```

First question : I don't understand how you can declare constructor like this..Second what is the purpose of AthenticationHeader class? is it also abstract?

Comment: This code would not compile -  not least because the constructor name mismatches the class name (`AthenticationHeader` vs `AuthenticationSoapHeader`). I also note the use of the `[Serlializable]` attribute - I suspect this is a typo too? When asking questions about why code works or doesn't work, it's *critical* you post the *exact* code that is relevant - otherwise we are going to end up answering the wrong question, wasting our time and yours.

Answer (score 0):

The second class not abstraction so u need to write the code in the methods you write .. or to make your second class abstract 
But if u extended from abstract class why would you make the extended class abstract too 
You need to write body for each method you write in class just in abstract you don’t have to

Comment: I found this code in a project  and it compiles fine! however I tried to mimic it in Visual studio and I get compile error: constructor must have body

Comment: ayman: Notice that both SoapHeader (which is .net  library class) and the implementing class both declare constructors without body

Comment: @kogibail `AuthenticationSoapHeader` does not have constructor. On what bases you claim that the class has constructor?